# изменить текст названия кнопки Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, button

Сайт содержит одинаковую кнопку на всех страницах с описанием работодателей - пример: http://inspektorpraci.eu/o-firme/416_maktronik  - синяя кнопка с текстом "Хочу больше отзывов". Необходимо изменить этот текст.

код страницы выглядит так:

```
<div class="subscribe-cont">
<a href="#" class="subscribe-btn">Хочу больше отзывов</a>
<div class="subscribe-form">
<form id="subscribe-form" action="/o-firme/416_maktronik" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="SUs2RlVxeGk5Il4.BTcBMT95ehBtSShbej1MLiZGPCcDA10vPQgSIQ=="> <div class="form-group field-subscribe-email required">
<input type="text" id="subscribe-email" class="form-control" name="Subscribe[email]" placeholder="Ваш Email для подписки" aria-required="true">
<div class="help-block"></div>
</div> <button type="submit" class="subscribe-submit">Получить</button> </form> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> http://inspektorpraci.eu/o-firme/416_maktronik - синяя кнопка с
>   текстом "Хочу больше отзывов". Необходимо изменить этот текст.

Ухх... ну и задачки пошли

Для примера, новый текст пусть будет - **Новый текст**, тогда:

```
<a href="#" class="subscribe-btn">Хочу больше отзывов</a>
```

это строчку заменяем на:

```
<a href="#" class="subscribe-btn">Новый текст</a>
```

Не благодарите

Answer (score 0):

> Если вы используете yii2, то используйте ее правильно. Форма привязуется к модели, которую она заполняет `$model`. Все манипуляции делаются в контроллере. Вот с документации:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Вход', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?> //Вход - это имя. Подставляете какое вам нужно.
        </div>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

> Вот создание кнопки (1) обычной (2) submit (3) reset так же с документации yii2:

```
<?= Html::button('Нажми меня!', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?= Html::resetButton('Сбросить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```